# How to get loggedin user session in magento

Tags: magento2, php

I created a module,that show list of user . I want to show that page to any user who is logged-in magento2 admin panel

```
// world.php

<?php
namespace Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Controller\Hello;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
class World extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $pageFactory;
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        var_dump($customerSession->isLoggedIn());
        $page_object = $this->pageFactory->create();;
        return $page_object;
    }
}
```

[image: Directory structure]

I want to check in world.php that a person is logged in or not if it is logged in allow him to proceed else return to magento admin panel login page

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: read question properly, and explore stackoverflow

Comment: I have read your "question" . which is no question. You explain us what you want to do, but not what your problem is

Comment: I created a module,that show list of user . I want to show that page to any user who is logged-in magento2 admin panel  that is a problem i have even implemented solution for that but its not working

Comment: cool. provide us information of what exactly is not working and provide us error-logs or stacktrace.

Comment: I am getting boolean false even a user in logged in admin panel. I update my code check it

Comment: When logged in the admin, you do not have a customer session. please read about session-handling in magento2

Comment: Yes i need admin session at frotend, how can i get that

Comment: you can't. Especially not from other users